# How does Standard Deviation (Error) change with sample size change in this scenario. Explanation needed for a nonprofessional

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, standard-error

I have this question that I want figured out.
A person's Blood pressure was taken 4 times,the mean of these 4 observations came out to be say 120mm of Hg  And the SD was 2.5.
Now we have taken 4 more observations and added their values in too. 
Question is: 1. What will happen to SD of BP? & 
2. With what percentage it should change? 30% 10% or 5%?

What I did was used standard error for means formula (s/n-underroot) and SE came out to be 1.25 with four observations and 0.883 with 8 samples. 
AM I doing it right? I know the SD is supposed to shrink with increasing sample size but by what value?
Can anyone please solve this for me with the context in mind that I am not a statistics student. I am in medicine (which is increasingly becoming aligned with statistics).

Comment: I don't think you'd expect the SD to change with sample size. As you point out, the standard error would decrease (given constant SD).

Comment: Thank you for the quick aswer. Can you please explain by which %age it ll change?

Comment: Is anyone worried about the effect of dependence here, or is that just me?

Comment: can you pl elaboarte that?